# IOException while reading hadoop sequence file

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm reading hadoop sequence file in java using following code

```
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf, SequenceFile.Reader.file(fileStatus.getPath()));
MyWritable1 key = (MyWritable1) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass(), conf);
MyWritable2 value = (MyWritable2) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), conf);
while(reader.next(key, value)){ //<- exception on this line
//some code
}
```

And I'm getting exception

> "java.io.IOException: some.package.MyWritable1@4142e91 read 59 bytes,
>   should read 231"

I'm writing to that file key-value pairs of the exact same classes MyWritable1 and MyWritable2.

What might be the issue here? Appreciate any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug. It was in MyWritable1 readFields function